# Google Cloud SDK throws Reachability Check failed after Command Line Tools update on macOS 12.4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

After the software update of Command Line Tools for Xcode to the version 13,4 the gcloud compute ssh command stopped working with the error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I'm not behind proxy or firewall.

What I've tried so far: updating google cloud sdk, then reinstalling, then removing and installing goole cloud sdk from scratch a number of times but the gcloud init command fails to complete with the same error. Downgrading command line tools to 13.2 didn't help. Updating certifi and launching "Install Certificates.command" neither.

output of "gcloud info --run-diagnostics --verbosity debug":

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.info] with arguments: [--run-diagnostics: "True", --verbosity: "debug"]
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...⠏DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): accounts.google.com:443
Checking network connection...⠛DEBUG: https://accounts.google.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338
Checking network connection...⠹DEBUG: https://accounts.google.com:443 "GET /ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 526
DEBUG: https://accounts.google.com:443 "GET /v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S352504070%3A1656098809680794&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2F&passive=1209600&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AX3vH3-l3sW9otbTScMC6LItjgqZXIpEl6jaKQLX4a-o3Z7M4L5oVPqMq_V_Vltgjce-HlGz4y0mFQ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Checking network connection...⠼DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com:443
Checking network connection...⠶DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dl.google.com:443
Checking network connection...⠧DEBUG: https://dl.google.com:443 "GET /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json HTTP/1.1" 200 190919
Checking network connection...done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    httplib2 cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)

    httplib2 cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)

    requests cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1beta1/projects (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

    requests cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/cloud-platform (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.


Do you have a network proxy you would like to set in gcloud (Y/n)?  n

ERROR: Network diagnostic failed (0/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

DEBUG: (gcloud.info) Some of the checks in diagnostics failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/info.py", line 91, in Run
    raise exceptions.Error('Some of the checks in diagnostics failed.')
googlecloudsdk.core.exceptions.Error: Some of the checks in diagnostics failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.info) Some of the checks in diagnostics failed.
```

output of "gcloud info":

```
Google Cloud SDK [391.0.0]

Platform: [Mac OS X, x86_64] uname_result(system='Darwin', node='gclouder.local', release='21.5.0', version='Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64', machine='x86_64', processor='i386')
Locale: (None, 'UTF-8')
Python Version: [3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08)  [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]]
Python Location: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin/python3]
OpenSSL: [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020]
Requests Version: [2.22.0]
urllib3 Version: [1.25.9]
Site Packages: [Enabled]

Installation Root: [/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  gsutil: [5.10]
  core: [2022.06.17]
  bq: [2.0.75]
System PATH: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin:/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/gclouder/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin:/Users/gclouder/.jenv/shims:/Users/gclouder/.jenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
Python PATH: [/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/virtenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/Users/gclouder/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]

Account: [None]
Project: [None]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True] (property file)

Logs Directory: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/gclouder/.config/gcloud/logs/2022.06.24/21.26.47.993939.log]

git: [git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)]
ssh: [OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: it was the corporate antivirus that started behaving this way after a software update